# react-native new architecture mixed with old one

Tags: react-native

I have application that is using `react-native` in version `0.67.5` which is not using new architecture yet. I'm using a lot of third party libraries that are not using new architecture and there is no plan to add support for it (lib is not maintained any more). Can I upgrade to `react-native` version `0.70.0` which is using new architecture without updating libraries? In other words is it possible to mix both architectures in a single app?